# How to add the same event handler to more than one element in D3

Tags: events, d3.js, handler

I made a bar chart where a numeric value is displayed as a `<text>` element inside the bar.

When a mouse hovers on a bar, additional info is displayed. However, when mouse cursor hovers over the text, the display doesn't show because the event handler is only attached to the `<rect>`.

I tried `d3.selectAll(rect text)`, but doesn't seem to work.

The only other way I can think of is to place them inside `<g>` and add event handler to the `<g>`.

Is there a more efficient way?

http://jbk1109.github.io/tennisMapWithPlayersListOnHover.html

Comment: Simple solution: set the `pointer-events` of the texts to `none`. Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41991941/5768908